# Loopback stops sending responses after 25-30 consequent requests

Tags: rest, http, loopbackjs

So, I have a vue frontend app connecting to my Loopback API and it all works well until you start changing views (sending GET requests) faster. Then I get request pending in Network tab of chrome dev tools. I tested the slower changing of views and it then doesn't return request pending so I'm guessing that this behavior is caused by some conf setting. Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look on what's going on loopback's side, say using `DEBUG=*` when starting your loopback app.

Comment: `{
  "final:after": {
    "strong-error-handler": {
      "params": {
        "debug": true,
        "log": true
      }
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: this is in middleware.development.json and app is in dev mode and still it shows nothing.